# adb over wifi connection problem

Tags: adb

I'm using wifi adb app on my mobile which is galaxy s3 mini 
when I type this command

```
adb connect 192.168.11.22:5523
```

it's connected fine, when I run the app over the android studio 
this message pop-up "session app Error installing APK"
and mobile disconnected and trying to connect it but it gives me this on CMD

```
unable to connec 192.168.11.22:5523
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726622/how-to-debug-in-android-studio-using-adb-over-wifi ?

Comment: it's working well when I changed the network

Comment: Some Wifi routers/networks disallow intra-network communication (from one client to another client).